# How do you go about implementing WEbUtil with Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

we are in the process of doing a Forms 10g upgrade from 6i and we cannot get the WebUtil utility to work, can anybody with first hand experience explain how you go about doing it

Comment: insufficient information. What errors are you getting ? Migration from 6i to 10g should be seamless.

Comment: i am looking for a step by step quide, I have been asked to implement this for the first time. I don't even know where to start

Comment: Start here: http://www.oracle.com/webapps/online-help/forms/10g/state/content/navId.3/navSetId._/vtTopicFile.web_util%7Cinstall%7Ehtm/

Answer (score 1):

1. For any Form that has commands that are now supported by WEBUTIL, you need to add the WEBUTIL.pll to that form as a reference objects.  Commands like TEXT_IO, READ_IMAGE_FILE, etc will continue to work as they are, but they are now occurring on the Application Server instead of the Client computer.  If you want it to be on the AS, don't do a thing.
2. Replace the calls that you now want to use the WEBUTIL option on with the WEBUTIL name.  This is simply adding CLIENT_ as prefix to the original call.  IE  TEXT_IO is CLIENT_TEXT_IO.
3. Make sure WEBUTIL is working on your server.  Oracle provides a test app to verify this and will support it's use.  Not to mention it is very well documented on Oracle's site.
4. Compile the Forms/Reports with the new commands on the server that WEBUTIL is installed.